# Making a linebreak in text file

Tags: php

i want to save every username in newline 
i want text file to look like this :

- name1
- name2

instead of this  :

name1name2

PHP code :

```
<?php
$username= $_POST['username']
file_put_contents("users.txt",$username);
?>
```

Comment: Where does `$_POST['username']` come from?

Comment: from the html file lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$username = "\n".$_POST['username'];
file_put_contents("users.txt",$username, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

since you seemingly write at the end of the existing file, you have to prepend a linebreak to it.

on a side note: you should always be very careful when processing unfiltered user data.

Comment: but file_put_contents overwrites the file. Unless you pass FILE_APPEND as the third parameter.

Comment: @Andrew don't be lazy! what about checking documention yoursefl? http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php